# How do they film new born babies?

Tags: film-techniques

Movies frequently show babies being born in outside environment and judging by the look the babies do seem extremely close to new borns. Unless we are tricked by CGI, how do they film such scenes?

I would imagine it is a great risk for small babies to be exposed to outside conditions at such early stage.

Comment: If I had to guess... they use either fake babies or preemies that are actually older than they look but since they started out so small, they look like newborns even a month or two later.

Comment: I imagine there are all sorts of different methods that have been used from fake babies to covering a real baby with gross looking gel. Question seems a little too broad IMO.